Jackson YAML Missing Method Issue in Java Application
I am working on upgrading a JAVA application.
I am working with Gradle 8.5, and upgrading to JAVA 17 and Spring Boot 3.2.5
While working on the upgrades, I ran into an issue involving com.fasterxml.jackson.* libraries.
Prior, troubleshooting, the only jackson library I had was:
org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.4
The error message I received stated:
NoSuchMethodError: void com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.createChildObject(int, int)
I did some rather extensive research and tried a fair number of possible resolutions.
The first thing I tried was adding in the com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat-yaml library. I initially attempted with version 2.13.0, but this didn't seem to resolve the issue.
I ran ./gradlew dependencyInsight -dependency jackson to see what version(s) it might be calling in. I found it bouncing between version 2.12.x and 2.15.4. Notating this, I attempted to force version 2.15.4 by adjusting the package versions that were bouncing around until all were calling version 2.14.x or 2.15.4 and setting the dependency implementation to specifically call version 2.15.4.
This didn't resolve the issue either. So I then tried updating the packages to versions using 2.15.4 or later... Which also didn't work.
I then tried implementing all of the related jackson libraries and pointing them all to version 2.15.4 (jackson-core, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-yaml, jackson-datatype-jdk8, etc...). Unfortunately, that also didn't seem to make a difference.
I tried following some of the suggestions found here:
Object Mapper - YAMLFactory - exception due to missing _createContentReference method
But this didn't seem to work either and added new problems in which other methods were now missing...
I am kinda at a loss here and could really use some suggestions.

Edited for what solved this for me:
I spent 2+ days troubleshooting this problem. Nothing I could find gave me a working answer. I couldn't even find the cause of the issue. Even verifying that only the desired version and that all dependencies resolved successfully, and were not being downgraded, the issue persisted.
I was able to resolve this finally by creating a buildscript {} above the plugins {} section to force jackson-core to resolve only as the desired version.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
